# Create row using RowGateway

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I've got class based on TableGateway:

```
namespace Model\Table;

class Meter extends AbstractTable
{
    protected $tableName = 'meter';

    public function __construct($adapter, $features = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($this->tableName, $adapter, $features);
    }
}
```

Here's my factory method:

```
Table\Meter::class => function(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $dbAdapter = $container->get(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::class);
    $features = [
        $container->get(MetadataFeature::class),
        $container->get(RowGatewayFeature::class),
    ];

    return new Table\Meter($dbAdapter, $features);
}
```

Now, if I fetch existing row, try to change some value and then invoke save() method, everything is OK:

```
$row = $this->select()->current();
$row->name = 'some new name';
$row->save();
```

But what if I need to create new row? How can I fetch RowGateway object, populate it and save?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create an instance of the `RowGateway`. And you'll need a reference to the DbAdapter for that. Populate the new instance of the `RowGateway` and just save it.

## Option 1: create an instance in your controller.

If you supply the DbAdapter to your controller via a factory:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Db\RowGateway\RowGateway;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class MeterController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
     */
    private $dbAdapter;

    public function __construct(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $dbAdapter)
    {
        $this->dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function insertAction()
    {
            $rowGateway = new RowGateway('id', 'meter', $this->dbAdapter); 
            $rowGateway->name = $this->params()->fromRoute('name');
            $rowGateway->save();
    }
}
```

## Options 2: provide an instance to your controller.

Another approach would be to provide the RowGateway itself to the controller as a prototype and clone it there when needed:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Db\RowGateway\RowGateway;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class MeterController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Db\RowGateway\RowGateway
     */
    private $rowGatewayPrototype;

    public function __construct(RowGateway $prototype)
    {
        $this->rowGatewayPrototype = $prototype;
    }

    public function insertAction()
    {
            $rowGateway = clone $this->rowGatewayPrototype; 
            $rowGateway->name = $this->params()->fromRoute('name');
            $rowGateway->save();
    }
}
```

The factory could look like this:

```
MeterController::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $rowGateway = new RowGateway('id', 'meter', $container->get(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::class));

    return new MeterController($rowGateway);
}
```